AWS managed apache flink. "<someuuid>pyflink/bin/pyflink-udf-runner.sh": error=13, Permission denied " not using udfs
I'm trying to run a very simple application in AWS-flink.

Apache flink 1.18
Kinesis connector 1.18
Python apache flink == 1.18
jar dependencies collected with a pom.xml for the flink-connector-kinesis 4.2.0-1.18
Saved the "uber-jar" into pyflink/lib/
Both python3.10 and 3.8 fail the exact same way.
Locally all runs fine, but whenever I start the job in aws it breaks with the permission denied on a worker folder.

Apparently, the file in the worker isn't accessible for the worker user (?)
This is the code, which I kept watering down until I got to this.
from pyflink.datastream.stream_execution_environment import StreamExecutionEnvironment


def main():
    env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()
    try:
        env.from_collection(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']).map(lambda x: x).map(print)
        env.execute('executethis')
    except Exception as ex:
        print('EXCEPTION!!!! ', ex)
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

The stacktrace (from the flink dashboard):
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create stage bundle factory!
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.runners.python.beam.BeamPythonFunctionRunner.createStageBundleFactory(BeamPythonFunctionRunner.java:656)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.runners.python.beam.BeamPythonFunctionRunner.open(BeamPythonFunctionRunner.java:281)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.python.process.AbstractExternalPythonFunctionOperator.open(AbstractExternalPythonFunctionOperator.java:57)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.python.process.AbstractExternalDataStreamPythonFunctionOperator.open(AbstractExternalDataStreamPythonFunctionOperator.java:85)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.python.process.AbstractExternalOneInputPythonFunctionOperator.open(AbstractExternalOneInputPythonFunctionOperator.java:117)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.python.process.ExternalPythonProcessOperator.open(ExternalPythonProcessOperator.java:64)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.RegularOperatorChain.initializeStateAndOpenOperators(RegularOperatorChain.java:107)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restoreGates(StreamTask.java:753)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskActionExecutor$SynchronizedStreamTaskActionExecutor.call(StreamTaskActionExecutor.java:100)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restoreInternal(StreamTask.java:728)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restore(StreamTask.java:693)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.runWithSystemExitMonitoring(Task.java:955)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.restoreAndInvoke(Task.java:924)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:748)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:564)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v32_1_2_jre.com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/tmp/python-dist-ea8c2605-8024-4255-a9d0-f9432a304ee7/python-files/py_site_packages38/py_site_packages38/pyflink/bin/pyflink-udf-runner.sh": error=13, Permission denied
at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v32_1_2_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:5022)
at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$SimpleStageBundleFactory.<init>(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:498)
at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$SimpleStageBundleFactory.<init>(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:482)
at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory.forStage(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:342)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.runners.python.beam.BeamPythonFunctionRunner.createStageBundleFactory(BeamPythonFunctionRunner.java:654)
15 more
**Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/tmp/python-dist-ea8c2605-8024-4255-a9d0-f9432a304ee7/python-files/py_site_packages38/py_site_packages38/pyflink/bin/pyflink-udf-runner.sh": error=13, Permission denied
**at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128)
at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.environment.ProcessManager.startProcess(ProcessManager.java:147)
at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.environment.ProcessManager.startProcess(ProcessManager.java:122)
at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.environment.ProcessEnvironmentFactory.createEnvironment(ProcessEnvironmentFactory.java:104)
at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$1.load(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:284)
at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$1.load(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:240)
at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v32_1_2_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3571)
at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v32_1_2_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2313)
at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v32_1_2_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2190)
at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v32_1_2_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2080)
at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v32_1_2_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:4012)
at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v32_1_2_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:4035)
at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v32_1_2_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:5013)
at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v32_1_2_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:5020)
19 more
Suppressed: java.lang.NullPointerException: Process for id does not exist: 7-1
at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v32_1_2_jre.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:921)
at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.environment.ProcessManager.stopProcess(ProcessManager.java:172)
at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.environment.ProcessEnvironmentFactory.createEnvironment(ProcessEnvironmentFactory.java:124)
29 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:340)
at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:271)
at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1107)

I expected the application to stop triggering that exception.

I added all kinesis analytics, permissions to the policy.
I added all s3 permissions to the policy to the prefix where the code lives.
I added all kinesis permissions to the input and output streams.
I added all kinesis analytics v2 analytics permissions to the policy.
I added the cloudwatch permissions as the documents say.
chmod 777 the packages before putting them in the .zip that contains the application.
I made the .jars match the apache flink 1.18 version in aws, as well as limiting the python requirement to also be 1.18.
I downgraded my python to 3.8 so that the libraries and all from python were flink1.18 for python 3.8.
I got rid of all unnecessary code and any kinesis or anything I was using.
I added the try/except.
I have all the libraries in an uber-jar (which is referenced in the jarfile) property.
I've looked for hours and hours on the internet and there are some things similar but not the same. The closest is https://lists.apache.org/thread/8b5kbf3prvrr0jo1bhk1y91osmr76v5r  but that fella is using UDF, apparently, which I'm not.

Also, I don't think I know how to change permissions on the file when running from the AWS managed-service. That'd be the first thing to try, but I don't know if that's even possible.
Thanks.

OK, I figured it out. The answer is very dumb but it is:

In some document I had read I needed to copy EVERYTHING from my virtualenv as pyfiles dependencies. That's not true: it's everything that NON-FLINK related!

Somehow having the flink dependencies within the pyfiles caused the engine to unwrap it into a 'double' folder: py_site_packages38/py_site_packages38/pyflink (instead of just py_site_packages38/pyflink). This new folder getting restrictive permissions.
That fixed it. I hope if someone has that same problem ever this helps out.
[ALSO, I realized that as of 2024-05, AWS' python version used in the managed flink is 3.10, so I can revert back to 3.10]
